# getByte() is returning same byte[ ] for different Strings

Tags: java, arrays, public-key-encryption, session-keys

I am generating a Session key, that changes every time i run the program.
But when i am converting it into BYTE ARRAY then Byte Array generated is same every time i run the program . IT should be different right?
Here is my code

```
Key key;
SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
generator.init(rand);
generator.init(256);
key = generator.generateKey();
String key1=key.toString();
byte[] genratesessionKey1 = key1.getBytes();
System.out.println("SESSION KEY IS(Byte format)   "+genratesessionKey1.toString());
```

Then i also used one dummy string. and then i generated its Byte[]. Then i changed the value in that string and generated its Byte[] Again. Still it returns the same result.

```
String test2="yadav";
String key1=key.toString();
byte[] genratesessionKey1 = key1.getBytes();
byte[] g2=test.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] g3=test.getBytes();              
System.out.println("Session key in String   "+key1);
System.out.println("Testing Byte Format   "+g2);
System.out.println("Testing Byte Format 2   "+g3);
```

Why Its happening.Any Suggestions will be appreciated

[First Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1awYU.png)

[Second Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfhIN.png)

Comment: Could you give us the entire code? I don't see where test is coming from

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example of the problem. The code you've provided is *almost* a working example, but not quite. I assumed references to `test` should be `test2` (`"yadav"`), and the code functioned as I would expect--that is to say, **not** what you described. So please provide a working example.

Comment: You do know that `toString()` on a byte array doesn't actually print out the byte contents, right?  So, what are you looking at to determine that the byte array is always the same?  Please post your output.

Comment: yeah IN String test2="yadav"; when i change it to String test2="yadav1234";

Comment: it still returns the same byte [ ] for both string .. that should be different right?

Comment: Please post the output of your `System.out.println()` statements.

Comment: @sstan yeah just want to know why its returning the Same byte[ ]  After( execution with first value) i change the String value.

Comment: And basically, I'm saying that I don't actually believe you.  I'm saying that you are not comparing the byte arrays correctly.  Please show your output.

Comment: I have added the Executions of Same program. Session key is changing but the byte[ ] is same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the code won't compile nor run. What will (omitting imports and class) is

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
           throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
      Key key;
      SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
      KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      generator.init(rand);
      generator.init(256);
      key = generator.generateKey();
      String key1 = key.toString();
      byte[] genratesessionKey1 = key1.getBytes();
      System.out.println("SESSION KEY IS(Byte format)   " 
                             +  genratesessionKey1.toString());

      String test2="yadav";
      byte[] g2 = test2.getBytes("UTF-8");
      byte[] g3 = test2.getBytes();              
      System.out.println("Session key in String   " + key1);
      System.out.println("Testing Byte Format   " + g2);
      System.out.println("Testing Byte Format 2   " + g3);

      System.out.println("Session key in String   "
                                     + Arrays.toString(genratesessionKey1));

   } // main(String[])
```

The output would be

```
SESSION KEY IS(Byte format)   [B@1c53fd30
Session key in String   javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe8e54
Testing Byte Format   [B@50cbc42f
Testing Byte Format 2   [B@75412c2f
```

This just shows arrays inheriting `Object.toString()` in the sense of showing the (useless) address as hash value. Hence, `toString()` lets all arrays look alike no matter what length or content.
Probably, Mudit wants to see the array's content. Adding

```
System.out.println("Session key in String   "
                                     + Arrays.toString(genratesessionKey1));
```

yields

```
Session key in String   [106, 97, 118, 97, 120, 46, 99, 114, 121, ....
```

Rationale: Downward compatibility forbade to enhance the (useless to repeat me) method `toString()` of all Arrays. Hence, what Mudit and many others expect was put as static methods in the helper class `java.util.Arrays` since Java5.

Comment: When i use Arrays.toString(byteArray) ... its changing but i have to encrypt it and pass it into that byte[ ] format , so the encryption returned will have right result for every session key generated on each execution of program

Answer (score 3):

You can't rely on calling `toString()` on a byte array to inspect its contents.  The returned value doesn't tell you what the bytes are.

If you really want to check the contents of a byte array and see whether it changes or not, use `Arrays.toString(byteArray)` instead.  And then you should be able to verify that the byte array does indeed change.

Comment: When i use Arrays.toString(byteArray) ... its changing but i have to encrypt it and pass it into that byte[ ] format , so the encryption returned will have right result for every session key generated on each execution of program

Answer (score 0):

I would use DatatypeConverter I've used it with my Security project and it worked like a charm...

Comment: Just use [`Base64`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) No need to use obscure `DatatypeConverter`.

Comment: Fair answer erikson but it's just another converter

Comment: They really aren't equivalent. `Base64` is designed and supported as a solution for any base-64 requirements, with configurable line-length and white space handling, multiple standardized symbol sets, etc.

Comment: @erickson i want to encrypt that byte [ ] . so if i use byte[].toString() and then encrypt it using session key . will it be wrong ?

Comment: because i can not figure out how to encrypt a byte[] using a Session key in java

Comment: @Mudit Yes, it will be wrong. The result of `toString()` called on a `byte[]` doesn't tell you anything about the content of the array, as you demonstrated yourself. Also, you can't encrypt strings. Encryption APIs require `byte[]` input. So stop trying to convert it to a `String` unnecessarily. Only after it's encrypted, if you need text, you can encode the cipher text with base-64.